# Konica FS-1 Film Rewind Mechanism Not Working

Tags: film, repair

I recently bought a Konica FS-1 and took a test roll of shots to make sure everything was working.

Everything was fine until I rewound the film. I pressed the film rewind button in and then manually cranked it until the counter went down to 1 and I could no longer rewind. When I opened the back, however, the film was NOT rewound into the camera.

I was able to take it to a local photo shop and they got it unstuck and developed it and everything came out nicely, but I want to figure out what's wrong with the rewind mechanism before I load another roll in so it doesn't get stuck again.

I can't find much information about the camera online enough that I could figure out and address the issue myself, so I'm coming here in the hopes that anyone has any insights!

Comment: You can find the manual online here:  https://cameramanuals.org/konica/konica_fs-1.pdf

Comment: It's odd that you got to the point where you could no longer rewind. Most/all cameras that I've owned let me manually rewind until the cows came home, lulled by a once per revolution snick of the film leader. The fact that the images were not ruined implies to me that you rewound gently enough that the leader didn't pop off the take-up spool as it normally would. This is probably not a problem with the camera.